# error with "as" when creating a computed column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a database for hospital visits and I want to alter the "Visit" table and add a new column which shows the total cost for the patients medication (by multiplying charge(from table "medication")*quantity(from table "getsmed")).

However, I wrote this code in MySQL workbench but it won't run and would under line the world "as" with the caption ("as" is not valid in this position, expecting: BIT, BOOL, BOOLEAN, DATETIME, TIME, ENUM...)

```
alter table visit
add total_charge as (medication.Mcharge*getsmed.Quantity)
;
```

Comment: Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html and provide a data type for total_charge,BTW you cannot access another table(s)  or use a function to do so. AND I'm not convinced storing a computeable column is a good thing

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you need to specify a type when adding a computed column:

```
alter table visit
    add total_charge decimal(20, 4) as (Mcharge * Quantity);
```

However, a computed column can only directly reference columns values in the same row.  It cannot "reach out" to other tables.  This gives you two choices:

1. Use a user-defined function to retrieve a value from another table.
2. Use a view rather than a computed column.

I would recommend the second solution.

I can't actually suggest any specific code, because you have not provided enough information in the question.

Comment: 'Stored functions and user-defined functions are not permitted' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html  I assume you mean outwith a computed column?